# .addClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first time working with `.addClass()`. 
In my project, I need to display notifications on a dummy phone screen (an image of iPhone). A notification has a `title` and some `description`. This `title` and `description` is coming from a form on the same `webpage`. To compose this notification, I am doing:

```
var notificationText = $('#title').val().addClass('title') + plainText.addClass("description");
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: $(...).val(...).addClass is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
So, as per the overwhelming requests, I did:

```
var notificationText = $('#title').addClass('title').val() + plainText.addClass("description");
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object sss has no method 'addClass'
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/2/)

**UPDATE 2:** I do not need to style the description, so I removed the class related to it. Please see my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/7/). Now the problem is that the text in `title` is getting bold instead of the one copied in `#notifications`. It is not getting styled as per the CSS.

Comment: You should use `$('#title').addClass('title').val()`

Comment: Are you trying to build a JSON object?

Comment: `val()` returns a string, you can't add a class to a string ?

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to achieve as your question has several issues, not just your misuse of `addClass()`

Comment: 10 answers in 3 minutes... is this a record for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @MaxArt: and only a few that actually take into account the real problems :)

Comment: I don't know who has up-voted the question, As it has some serious issues

Comment: `plainText` is a Text content, How can you add class to it

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have removed that class as I wont be styling it. Please see Update 2.

Comment: @RahulDesai, See http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/14/

Comment: Added an answer *with the styling* (did not see update 2). Give it a try. Hope that is the sort of result you wanted.

Comment: +1 for the various fiddles you provided. Up to that point it was very hard to figure out what you actually wanted as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many answers in so little time... *sigh*

I gathered what I think you wanted. Try this one:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7b3j2/13/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'description' );

    $('#title').focus();    

    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var html=CKEDITOR.instances.description.getSnapshot();
        var divEle=document.createElement("DIV");
        divEle.innerHTML=html;
        var plainText=(divEle.textContent || divEle.innerText);

        var $title = $('<span></span');
        $title.addClass('title');
        $title.text($('#title').val());

        var $desc = $('<span></span');
        $desc.addClass('description');
        $desc.text(plainText);

        $('form').append($title);
        $('form').append($desc);
    });
});
```

You can obviously chain some of the span operations, but I left them readable for now. Shorter version would look like:

```
    var $title = $('<span></span').addClass('title').text($('#title').val());
    var $desc = $('<span></span').addClass('description').text(plainText);
    $('form').append($title).append($desc);
```

As you probably know by now, but for completeness, the initial errors were the result of trying to apply `jQuery` methods to `string` objects. This solution creates new `jQuery` `span` objects that can then be styled and appended to the form.

Comment: Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/2/ I need to use the classes added to style the HTML elements.

Comment: I think I worked out what you actually wanted (had to guess from all the clues). See what you think.

Comment: Very long slow race :)

Comment: I won! I won! ...and the grand prize is... one upvote! I'd like to thank my mum for encouraging my computer programming, my tutors at UNI and... who am I forgetting... Oh yes, I'd like to thank `Alan Turing` for starting the whole industry... Thank you. Love to all :>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying add class to a value, which is definitely is not a `jQuery` object

Try this instead:

```
$('#title').addClass('title').val()
```

Comment: Please see Update 2 (sorry, I know its annoying!)

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` can only be performed on jQuery objects and returns a jQuery object - that's what makes it chainable. You can't add a class to a string.

So, in this code, there are actually two mistakes:

1) `plainText.addClass` - `plainText` is a string, and not a jQuery object. You must add the class to the element you created (in your case, the `divEle` element), but, since `addClass` only works with jQuery objects, you must convert your div to a jQuery element first. You can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
$(divEle).addClass('description');
```

2) `addClass` returns a jQuery object, so you can't concatenate it with a string.

**EDIT**: Just realized that you're appending `notificationText` (which is a string) to the DOM. You must convert it to a div and add the div to the DOM.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/17/

Answer (score 0):

For adding a class, you have to use

```
$('#title').addClass('title');
```

If you want to get the value, you can use

```
$('#title').addClass('title').val()
```

Comment: But how does that work together with the `+ plainText.addClass("description");`  that the OP has?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `addClass` first

```
$('#title').addClass('title');
```

### Update

To get the code fully working you should split up the line like so.

```
var notificationText = $('#title').val() + ' ' + plainText;
$('#title').addClass('title');
$(plainText).addClass("description");
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/6/)

### Final Update

So what we actually want to do here is:

- get the values of the content
- append them on submit and style the appended text

**Example**

```
// Get the text.
var notificationText = $('#title').val() + ' ' + plainText;

// Append to form.
$('form').append('<span class="summary">' + notificationText + '</span>');

// CSS styling
.summary {
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

### See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/15/)

Comment: But how does that work together with the `+ plainText.addClass("description");`  that the OP has?

Comment: @Archer "text[object Object]"

Comment: @ColinBacon: In yourt fiddle, the text in the textbox is getting bold. I actually want the text in notification to be `bold` and `display: block`

Comment: @RahulDesai thanks for the info.  See the final update with fiddle.

Comment: @ColinBacon: The appended text is not getting styled in your updated fiddle :(

Comment: @RahulDesai Sorry pasted wrong link.  Please try new link again.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake done by you:

```
<div id="title"><div>
$('#title').val().addClass('title')
```

->Now here  `$('#title').val()` will give that particular element value.

->`$('#title').val().addClass()` you are adding class to that value.

Use this:

```
$('#title').addClass();
```

As you cannot add class to element's value.

You should addClass to particular element as addClass internally will add attribute class to that element.
So finally solution becomes:

```
 $('#title').addClass('title').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to add class over value instead of element.

```
$('#title').val().addClass('title')  //it is wrong
```

replace it with:

```
$('#title').addClass('title')
```

if plainText is not an element object you initialize by

```
var plainText = $('#anotherId');
```

will also cause this error.

Comment: But the OP's code also has `+ plainText.addClass("description");` on that line...

Answer (score 0):

Considering `#title` is the id of the element. 
You can directly need to add classname to it.

```
$('#title').addClass('className');
```

where `className` is the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

While `addClass` and `val()` are both methods on the jQuery object, `val()` is not chainable like `addClass` is. When you do `$('#title').val()` you aren't returning the *object*, you're only returning the string value of the element.

Use this instead:

```
$('#title').addClass('title');
```

And if you still need to get the value:

```
$('#title').addClass('title').val();
```

The reason why `plaintext` is producing an error is because you're trying to use the jQuery `addClass` method on a DOM node that has been natively created with `document.createElement("DIV");`. This will not work. To get it to work you either need to to define your new element with jQuery:

```
var divEle = $('<div></div>');
```

and then add the class:

```
divEle.addClass('description');
```

**Or** use the native `classname` method to add the class to the DOM node:

```
divEle.className = divEle.className + " description";
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Sorry, I initially linked to the wrong answer - I've now updated my comment to link to the answer that was first (and wasn't edited - at least, it definitely included `.val()` before this answer was posted). Not that I intend any criticism towards Andy, this answer is correct too.

Comment: @Andy Please see Update 2 (sorry, I know its annoying!)

Comment: @RahulDesai [You were adding the class to the wrong element](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2ETpH/2/)

Comment: @Andy Actually, I just want the title to be `bold` and `display: block`. The description need not be styled.

Comment: @RahulDesai, in the last fiddle you wrote, the title _was_ bold. By `display:block` do you mean not an input box, but just straight text?

Comment: Yes, just in the text. :)

Comment: [I guess you need to replace the input box with a div then.](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/2ETpH/9/)